# Algorithm that checks if a context free grammar generates infinite language that a DFA rejects

Tags: algorithm, context-free-grammar, formal-languages, automaton

I have a DFA A and a CFG G, then i have to check if G generates infinite words that A don't accept (rejected by A), and a nice complexity time.

I thought to construct a graph with the CFG and if it contains a directed cycle, then produces an infinite language. Vertices are the variables and for each production I draw some edges. The input are all words rejected by the DFA and when I found a cycle I can say that the CFG generates infinite language rejected by DFA A.

I don't know how to transform it in a algorithm or if my proposal is not correct and I have to create a new one.

Edit: Can I transform my cfg to CNF and then to a DFA ( with chomsky ).After, I try to find a cycle. But my transformed dfa can have less states than my dfa a... I need how to get the words rejected by DFA A in my cfg I think.

Answer (score 3):

Given CFG G, construct PDA B. Given DFA A and PDA B, construct PDA C such that C accepts L(C) = L(B) \ L(A), where \ is set difference. Now, L(C) is precisely the language of words accepted by the PDA B (hence generated by the CFG G) but not accepted, i.e. rejected, by the DFA A.

Now, the question is whether the language of B is infinite. We can do this. One way is to convert the PDA back into a CFG, and then put the CFG in CNF - removing unnecessary and unproductive symbols. Then, create a dependency tree among nonterminal symbols. If any remaining (productive) nonterminal symbol depends upon itself, i.e., there is a loop, then the language is infinite. Otherwise, the language is finite (empty, if there are no productive symbols remaining).

Comment: One last question. The complexity time of this algorithm is moreless O(n^2) right?

Comment: @JackFenn Good question; I'd need to do a little digging on each of the steps to see what the overall complexity is. O(n^2) should at least be a lower bound on the worst case, since the PDA for the difference language has that many states if the original DFA and PDA have the same number of states.